# I/O exception caught when processing request to {}->http://IP:80: Too many open files

Tags: java, rest, stress-testing

I have this architecture, 3 systems:

1. Back-end
2. Middleware
3. Front-end (Client application).

I have rest web service between back-end and middleware and also another different rest service between Front-end and middleware ( as I displayed in the below image)

[image]

As appeared in above image,Client is calling Middleware, and Middleware is calling Back-end rest service.

now everything is working fine when i run few requests, but when I started stress testing from client side ( I used JMeter to do this test and call middleware service), I started recieving this exception

[image]

I am using this code to call Back-end service:

```
public static String makeHttpPostCall(String url2, String param1, String type,
            String username, String password) throws IOException {

        String response1 = "";


        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();


            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url2);

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", param1));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);



            System.out.println("Response Code : "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));


            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response1 += line;
            }
            System.out.println("response1: "+ response1);
            return response1;
    }
```

please can anyone tell me where is the problem in Middleware or back-end, and why it happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not close the client http-connection. Try:

```
...
 }
            System.out.println("response1: "+ response1);

            client.close();

            return response1;
...
```

The exception shows that the error occurs when trying to open a new http connection. Mind that although it's a network connection, for the underlying OS it's just an open file descriptor.
If you only make a few calls, the connection may be discarded by gc and everything seems fine. Making a stress test will open as much "files" as you're allowed to and then throws this exception.

Comment: you mean the problem in middleware, because I did not close the http connection?

Comment: I don't know whether its left, middle or right, it's exactly in that lines you have striked out in your screenshot.

Comment: And anyway it's always good practice to close any unused conenctions after usage and, furthermore, it doesn't cost anything and is usually without any harm.

Comment: Thanks I will change code, do same stress testing and tell you what happened.

Comment: I run this test again, and number of exception is decreased from 1000 / 4000 to 10/4000, can I remove these 10 also?

Comment: I don't know your stress test, but probably there are multiple parallel requests running which are again using too may descriptors at a time. In this case, you can only increase the number of allowed open files, look at `ulimit`.

Comment: can you tell me how to use ulimit and where? is there any relation between this error and my application server (JBOSS) configuration?